# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [20][20]' to 'char ** '？

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

My Code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_pointer(char **str);
void print_array(char *str[20]);
void print_array2(char str[20][20]);
void print_array3(char str[][20]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[20][20] = {"test1", "test2", "test3"};

    print_pointer(str);
    print_array(str);
    print_array2(str);
    print_array3(str);

    return 0;
}

void print_pointer(char **str)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", str[i]);
    }
}
void print_array(char *str[20])
{
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", str[i]);
    }
}
void print_array2(char str[20][20])
{
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", str[i]);
    }
}

void print_array3(char str[][20])
{
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", str[i]);
    }
}
```

When I compile this code, there are two compile errors encountered:

1. `error C2664: 'print_pointer' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [20][20]' to 'char ** '`
2. `error C2664: 'print_array' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [20][20]' to 'char *[]'`

My question is what's the actually difference between these 4 functions?

Why `print_array` and `print_pointer` function could not work while `print_array2` and `print_array3` could work properly?

Comment: Could you please add the lines where are the errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char**` is a pointer to a pointer.

You want a pointer to an array (hint: it's not `char* []` either as this is an array of pointers equivalent to the above).

You need `char (*)[size]` (notice the brackets). This will happily take an input of the type `char[20][20]`. For the sake of completeness `char [][size]` is also equivalent (in both cases you need to specify the size of the second array).

Comment: so why does void print_array(char *str[20]) not work? it's char(*)[] format as you mentioned above.

Comment: It's not, `(char str[20])` might as well be `(char* str)`.

However `(char (*str)[20])` will work for `str[20][20]`

Comment: Can I direct you to this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724368/how-to-pass-a-2d-array-by-pointer-in-c

Comment: why one dimension array could interchange with pointer, while two dimension array could not?

Comment: Because there are differences between pointers and arrays :) You want a pointer to an array, not an array of pointers.

Comment: Stack Overflow has some excellent resources on pointers and arrays in C, have a browse around :)

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, this is where the idea that an array can be treated like a pointer falls apart.

"char[20][20]" denotes an array of 400 characters, laid out in a 20x20 fashion.  It is *not* an array of 20 pointers to arrays of 20 characters each.  Thus it would be incorrect to cast a char[20][20] to a char** (and if you did so explicitly, you'd get garbage results).

For the same reason (char[20][20] is not an array of pointers), you can't cast to char *[20].

It *is* an array of arrays, which is what you've declared for print_array2 and print_array3.