# Modifying a 2d array passed to a function

Tags: c, arrays

```
int print(int **a, int m, int n)
{
    int i, j, sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            sum = sum + *((a + i*n) + j);
        }       
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I got a garbage value instead of sum of the array elements. When I type-casted as

```
sum = sum + (int )*((a + i*n) + m));
```

I'm getting a correct answer. Why is that? But this method won't work for modifying the array elements. How can I do that?
Please check this link for reference. http://ideone.com/VRVAxW

Comment: Could you show a) how the array was created, b) what code you tried to use for modifying things?

Comment: Your code seems wrong in your sum line: `(a + i*n)` is actually an `int **`, thus `((a + i*n) + m)` is still an `int **` (thanks to pointer arithmetics) ... so `*((a + i*n) + m)` is an `int *`, not an `int`.

Comment: The question has been edited from `sum = sum + *((a + i*n) + m));` to `sum = sum + *((a + i*n) + j));`. Is that answering own question?

Comment: print((int **)array,2,3)       I got a error when i tried (int )*((a + i*n) + m)) = 5;

Comment: Well present a properly formatted question please and don't keep changing it.

Comment: It was a mistake on my part i meant j not m

Comment: There is a **reason** why SO asks you to post the MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Diamondhead see that question asked in the first comment? Hows about you answer that by providing an [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *that **we** can compile and run* and exhibits your problem. Judging by that cast in your comment `print` call my crystal ball tells me your array being passed in to this is declared `int ar[m][n];` or similar, which is **not** compatible with `int**`, and your answer to a compiler barking  errors was forcing that cast. From the looks of your [linked failure](http://ideone.com/GQwVOa) which is far more complete than your question, that's it.

Comment: BY the time you get around to posting a question on SO, all such typos etc. should have long ago been resolved:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sum = sum + *( *(a + i ) + j));
```

Take into account that the function can be called for an array declared like

```
int * a[m];
```

or for a pointer declared like

```
int **a;
```

Otherwise you should define the function the following way provided that your compiler supports Variable Length Arrays

```
int print( int m, int n, int a[][n] )
{
    int i, j, sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            sum = sum + *( *(a + i ) + j );
        }       
    }
    return sum;
}
```

As for this expression

```
 (int )*((a + i*n) + m)
```

that is equivalent to

```
 (int )*( a + i*n + m )
```

then in any case it is wrong.

Comment: Or the "classic" `sum += a[i][j];`

Comment: Yeah, it works that way, but I think it's at least worth mentioning that `*(*(a+i)+j)` is equivalent to `a[i][j]`. (And btw, you have an extra `)` in your answer, which I assume to be a typo)

Comment: a[i][j] doesnt work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724368/how-to-pass-a-2d-array-by-pointer-in-c

Comment: @Diamondhead Your program referered in the first comment is simply invalid. The types of the parameter and of the argument are not compatible.

Comment: `a[i][j]` (or the solution given by @VladfromMoscow) works if an `int **` is given as a parameter to your function. Remember that an `int [][]` is NOT compatible with an `int **`, and that your function takes an `int **` as an argument. (This was explained in the question you linked)

Comment: @NiBZ Sorry a[i][j] is not working when int ** is given as a parameter.Pease check this link http://ideone.com/gCPtsT.I need the answer when int ** is given as a parameter

Comment: @Diamondhead In your example, `arr` is declared as `int arr[][3]`, not as `int **arr`, and thus `arr` is not an `int **`. Your cast at line 17 does not change this.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why would someone intentionally make life hard for himself. There's not difference for a compiler anyway.

Comment: @meaning-matters  Each programmer should  learn how to use pointers.