# How to pass 2d arrays of struct using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct piece Piece;
struct piece{
char color;
char symbol;
};
int readPiece(Piece * p[]);
```

// Because my code is quite long . I didn't put all of them here.

```
int main(void){
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    Piece input[LEN][LEN];
    readPiece(input);
    return 0;
}
```

//read in 16*2 specific characters .

```
int readPiece(Piece * p[]){
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;


    while(row < LEN){
       col = 0;
       while(col < LEN){
          scanf("%c%c",&(p[row][col] .color), &(p[row][col].symbol)); 
          if((p[row][col].color == 'R' || p[row][col].color == 'G' || p[row][col].color == 'B' || p[row][col].color == 'Y') && (p[row][col] . symbol == '*' || p[row][col].symbol == '^' ||  p[row][col].symbol == '#' || p[row][col].symbol == '$')){
             getchar();

          }else{
             return 0;
          }
          col ++;     
       }
       row ++;
    }
    return 1;

}
```

// I just start learning C language. I try to pass a 2d struct by pointer into a function but when I compile it , it shows 'incompatible pointer types passing'.
So I wanna ask what's the right way to pass a 2d struct into a function and why mine is not working. Thanks.

Comment: What you've provided looks fairly close to an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It looks as though you need to define `LEN` and include `<stdio.h>`, but that's about all.  Providing more would not have been good.  So well done on that.  Why don't you use `int readPiece(Piece p[LEN][LEN]);`?  It seems like a reasonable way to pass a 2D array of a structure type.  (You don't use `row` or `col` in your reduced `main()`.)

Comment: Yeah I know int readPiece(Piece p[LEN][LEN]) will work but I am learning pointer right now. I just want to practice and I can't understand why this method is not working . Or should I use **p instead?Thx

Comment: Just as you pass a 2d array in a function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724368/how-to-pass-a-2d-array-by-pointer-in-c

Comment: Well yeah I saw that. But I don't get it for the main function int main (int argc, char * argv[]) it works pretty well. I think my function code should work as well because they have similar prototype.

Comment: The `int *p[]` notation denotes an array of pointers to `int`.  What you've got in `main()` is not an array of pointers to `int`, but a 2D array of `int`.  These are not the same; they're not even all that similar — but, just to make sure you get the maximum confusion out of it all, you use the same notation `array[index1][index2]` to access elements of both!

Answer (score 2):

I too came across this problem recently. Use `Piece (*p)[LEN]` in the function definition header (and the function declaration) instead of `Piece *p[]`.

`*p[]` will be an array of pointers whereas `(*p)[]` will be pointer to array.

Try reading this as well:
[C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Comment: Maybe "in the function prototype in both the declaration and the definition" would be precise, if a little wordy.

Comment: Using an array pointer as parameter is fine, but the syntax is a bit confusing. Better to use `Piece p [LEN][LEN]` which is equivalent but much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`Piece * p[]` means an array of pointers so it is the wrong type.

The function should be declared as `int readPiece(Piece p[LEN][LEN);`.
Or if you prefer, `int readPiece(size_t length, Piece p[length][length]);`.