# Why am I getting 'segmentation error' while using double pointer as an argument for a 2-D array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The problem is about taking input of a 4X5 matrix and shifting each of its rows circularly left by 2 places. Like if input is {1,2,3,4,5} the output should be {3,4,5,1,2}. I wrote the following code for the same. But I am getting 'segmentation fault(core dumped)' error. Can you help me with this. Also I am a bit susceptible  about sending a 2-d array to function with **p  argument. DO COMMENT ON THIS ALSO. I want to know why I am getting the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void shift(int **);
int main()
{
    int i,j,a[4][5];
    printf("Enter the elements of the 4X5 matrix:\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Entered Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

        shift(a);

        printf("The new array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void shift(int **p)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        int temp[2] = {**(p+i),*(*(p+i)+1)};
        *(*(p+i)+0) = *(*(p+i)+2);
        *(*(p+i)+1) = *(*(p+i)+3);
        *(*(p+i)+2) = *(*(p+i)+4);
        *(*(p+i)+3) = temp[0];
        *(*(p+i)+4) = temp[1];
    }
}
```

Expected Result - Rotated Array
Actual Result - Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a 2D array by pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724368/how-to-pass-a-2d-array-by-pointer-in-c)

Comment: Rather than using nested arrays, a better solution in ~ 99% of cases is to represent a 2D array as an `int*`, and to perform the index computation yourself. All major linear algebra libraries do it that way.

Comment: You can use `int*` in place of `int [n]` because an array when used in an expression "decays" to a pointer to the first element. The same goes for 2D arrays, they are actually just arrays of arrays. The first element of a 2D array is a 1D array. And so it decays to a pointer to such an array: `int (*)[n]`. That's why you can't use `int**` because it means something else entirely. So you could write the function as `void shift (int (*arr)[5])` but that's quite hard to read. The method shown in the accepted answer is easier to read and completely equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the array elements of a 2D array like that only works for 2D arrays. Instead of declaring it like this:

```
void shift(int **p)
```

You should change it to this:

```
void shift(int p[4][5])
```

And the same for the prototype of the function. [Click here](https://onlinegdb.com/H1OAVNBRE) for a demo.

Comment: Does that make any difference? Also I used the pointer notation so that I can change the value at the addresses using a void function. Fetching the elements using a matrix notation, I can't do much with a void function.

Comment: @SukritKapil A 2D array doesn't dereference twice

Comment: @ThomasJager Actually I did the same question for a 1-D array. Using *p as an argument. Should not **p work the same way for a 2-D array.

Comment: @SukritKapil it works this way for me this way and also on online OnlineGDB (I added a link to that). `**p` works, but only for jagged arrays, which is when you have an array of pointer pointing to more arrays.

Comment: @SukritKapil A double-pointer could be used as an array of pointers, which you could index into twice. However, a double-pointer is different. The compiler knows that doing `[2][3]` on an `int **` is completely different from doing it on an `int [4][5]`. The former will add `2 * sizeof(int *)` to the pointer address, get the `int *` at that address, add `3 * sizeof(int)` to that address, and get the `int` there. The latter will effectively dereference an `int *` with an index dependant on the indices used, and the size of all but one dimension.

Comment: @Blaze Thank you so much. It actually worked. Can you please help me why **p won't work?

Comment: @SukritKapil Thomas summed that up very well. If you want to do `**p`, you'll need a jagged array, which is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1083681/10411602

Comment: Thanks to all. Understood.

Comment: @SukritKapil Alternatively you can do `void shift(int x, int y, int arr[x][y]);` if you need a function accepting any 2D array.

Comment: @Lundin Alright, would that work because int x and int y are initialised earlier than arr[x][y] and so it does not give 'uninitialised array' error?

Comment: @SukritKapil They are parameters to the function. The array in the example is actually a variable-length array (VLA) but it "decays" into a pointer "between the lines".