# How to pass a 2d array as a double pointer to a function in c?

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, function-pointers

I'm trying to send a 2d array as a double pointer to a function but it keeps me showing this error

```
matp.c:15:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘read’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  read(a,r,c);
matp.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[(sizetype)(c)]’
 void read(int **,int,int);
  ^~~~
```

here is the code

```
void read(int **,int,int);
void disp(int **,int,int);
int main()
{
int r,c;

int a[r][c];
printf("\nEnter the elements of the matrix:\n");
read(a,r,c);

printf("\nThe entered matrix is:\n");
disp(a,r,c);
printf("\nThe transpose of the given matrix is :\n");
disp(a,c,r);

return 0;
}

void disp(int **a,int r,int c)
{
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<=r;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=c;j++)
    {
        printf("%d",*(j+*(&(a)+i)));
    }
}
return;
}
```

I tried to read a matrix and print it's transpose

Comment: Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724368/how-to-pass-a-2d-array-by-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The C compiler doesn't know the size, and therefore doesn't know how to deal with it.

Use:

```
printf("%d",*( (int*) a + i * c + j )));
```

And when calling convert:

```
disp((int**) a, r, c);
```

And be careful when printing the transposed matrix.
Just changing the size is not going to give you what you want.
You can print the transposed matrix like this:

```
void disp_transposed(int **a,int r,int c)
{
    int i,j;
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            printf("%d",*( (int*) a + i * c + j )));
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Also, using `<=r` and `<=c` will get you out of the bounds of your matrix(when `i == r` and/or `j == c`).