# How to pass a 2d array of struct elements to a function in C

Tags: c, struct, 2d

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int num;
} test;


void print_test1d(test *t){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d ",t[i].num);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void print_test2d(test **t){
    printf("%s\n","Assert");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            printf("%d\n",t[i][j].num);
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    
    test t[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        t[i].num = i;
    }
    
    print_test1d(t);


    test t2[5][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            t2[i][j].num = i*j;
        }
    }

    print_test2d(t2);    
}
```

I am hoping someone can explain why when I attempt to create a 2d
array of struct objects and pass them to the function print_test2d, I
receive a segfault when the 1d example works. Thanks in advance.

These were the error warnings when I compiled

```
tester.c: In function ‘main’: tester.c:43:18: warning: passing
argument 1 of ‘print_test2d’ from incompatible pointer type
[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     print_test2d(t2);
                  ^~ tester.c:17:6: note: expected ‘test ** {aka struct <anonymous> **}’ but argument is of type ‘test (*)[5] {aka
struct <anonymous> (*)[5]}’  void print_test2d(test **t){
```

And this was the output:

```
0 1 2 3 4  Assert Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a 2D array by pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724368/how-to-pass-a-2d-array-by-pointer-in-c)

Comment: It answers it perfectly!!! thanks for the quick response