# Pass two dimensional array in function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to pass two dimensional array in function, but is has two errors which I don't know why. I have some articles about passing two dimensional array in function but also can't understand why I fail.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// prototypes
void matrixSwap(double** matrix, int rows, int columns);

int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int COLUMNS = 5;

    double matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS] =
    {
      { 1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
      { 6,  7,  8,  9,  0},
      {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
      {16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
      {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
    };

    matrixSwap(matrix, ROWS, COLUMNS);
    /* it says
       1) argument of type "double (*)[5U]" is incompatible with parameter of type "double **"
       2) 'void matrixSwap(double *[],int,int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'double [5][5]' to 'double *[]'
    */
}

void matrixSwap(double** matrix, int rows, int columns) {}
```

Comment: Look into this answer, it is the same question and problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16724388/13687491

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a 2D array by pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724368/how-to-pass-a-2d-array-by-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multidimensional `double` array `matrix` you're trying to pass in the function `matrixSwap()` to the argument `double**`, actually doesn't represents a multidimensional array.

Use arrays correctly as shown:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const unsigned short MAXROWS = 5;

// prototypes
void matrixSwap(double matrix[][MAXROWS], int rows, int columns);

int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int COLUMNS = 5;

    double matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS] =
    {
      { 1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
      { 6,  7,  8,  9,  0},
      {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
      {16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
      {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
    };

    matrixSwap(matrix, ROWS, COLUMNS);
}

void matrixSwap(double matrix[][MAXROWS], int rows, int columns) {}
```

Just changed into `[][MAXROWS]` where `MAXROWS` contains an unsigned integer of value `5`.

---

The declaration:

```
void matrixSwap(double matrix[][MAXROWS], int rows, int columns)
```

is equivalent to:

```
void matrixSwap(double (*matrix)[MAXROWS], int rows, int columns)
```

Notice that here I've used `*matrix` and then appended `[MAXROWS]` which does the same job as `matrix[][MAXROWS]`.

So you may do the same thing in another way as follows:

```
void matrixSwap(double (*matrix)[MAXROWS], int rows, int columns) {
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This will give you the output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 0
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

To see if the `matrix` is successfully passed into the function by the new argument.

Comment: Note that `MAXROWS` must be the same as `ROWS` (and ideally would have the same constant)

Comment: @AlanBirtles, yes, the array size must be known to the compiler, variable number of lengths aren't allowed unless you use `std::vector<>` or use arrays with pointers.